# Sum fields and place into a view if ID's are the same

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of electricity usage over monthly periods in MS Access.  I want to create a table or a query that will only display the total sum of electricity usage.  Here's a sample of my starting table:

```
ID, MeterID, DateRead, kWh
--------------------------
1, 15256, 10/9/2010, 1710
2, 15256, 11/1/2010, 4790
3, 15256, 12/1/2010, 5390
4, 15256, 1/1/2011, 7590
5, 12557, 10/1/2010, 681
6, 12257, 11/1/2010, 710
7, 12257, 11/1/2010, 710
```

And so on.  I want to sum the kWh column where the Meter ID's are the same. So it would look like this

```
MeterID, kWh
------------
15256, Some sum
12257,Some sum
```

If I were writing this in C  I could do this in 2 seconds.  Unfortunately, this is my first real journey into SQL/Databases so I'm not very familiar with them.  Any help would be appreciated.  Sorry if it's trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT MeterID, SUM(kWh) FROM usage GROUP BY MeterID
```

SUM() is a aggregate function that goes through every row of your query and sums the argument (here `kWh`). You need the `GROUP BY` to tell SUM() to add `kWh` for the corresponding MeterID.

[GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: Thanks alot.  I forgot the GROUP BY qualifier, that explains it.